# Difference between unicast and multicast probe request

Tags: c#, wcf, ws-discovery

I was working on the WS-discovery implementation for my project. When I go through some documentation about the WS-Discovery, I found that, the probe message are of two types. One is  unicast probe message and other is multicast. I am new to WS-Discovery. I didn't get any more information about the difference between the unicast and multicast probe requests. I need to clarify my doubt that, Is the xml data for the unicast and multicast probe requests same?

Also at receiving side, can we know whether the probe is unicast or multicast?